# Is it possible to span a header of a celltable GWT

Tags: gwt, user-interface, celltable

I want to create a header in CellTable as follows.

[image]

The workaround I think of is to add a panel with "Main title" just above the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use GWT 2.5, you can use a customized `CellTableBuilder` to add your *Main Title* header line.